Ошибка "JavascriptException" python selenium
Пытаюсь вставить текст в поле с локатором //input[@name='tagName']
стандартный способ send_keys кидает ошибку JavascriptException.
Так же пробовал через js но текст не вводится
пробовал так:
def set_value_by_js(self, element, value):
    self.browser.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", element, value)
    self.browser.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1]);", element, value)
    self.browser.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = arguments[1];", element, value)

